# Cannot access ADFS end point /adfs/ls/

Tags: ssl-certificate, adfs2.0

I set up an ADFS environment Windows Server 2012 R2 by the following steps:

1. creating a certificate file;
2. Install ADFS through Server management;
3. Configure ADFS with the certificate file created in #1

the above 3 steps runs successfully but I cannot access the endpoint https://[DomainControllerName]/adfs/ls. Sometimes it shows 503 error page and sometimes it just says "the webpage is not available".

Does anyone encounter the similar problem? Please help. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid endpoint.

ADFS is expecting protocol parameters after that.

Try the metadata endpoint:

https://myserver.domain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Comment: Thanks, nzpcmad.
But that link you provided still cannot be visited. do I need to set something special in the IIS?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything with IIS. Does your DNS resolve the federation service name? Which should match to the SSL certificate?